# restrict access to staging instance on heroku for angular + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, angularjs, heroku

Is there a way we can prevent random people from looking at our staging site?  We are using an angular js single page js application which is precompiled/uglified into the rails public folder (rails is our backend).  All of this is hosted on heroku.

Some of the solutions for securing an app seems to involve rack middleware, but if the app is cached into an index.html in the public folder, doesn't that circumvent rails and rack stack entirely?

I don't think I can use .htaccess because heroku is not using apache for rails is it?

Just wondering if there is a way to do some ip filtering or even http basic authentication on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Rack based methods should work for you.  On Heroku static assets are still served by the application itself since there is not one of the traditional web servers (apache, nginx, etc...) sitting in front of the app and connected to the `public` folder.